# Fetching rows from database and making them links to other pages

Tags: php, html, database, hyperlink, oracle10g

I think the question title is not so accurate but here are the details of the problem i am facing.
I have Movies Database in Oracle10g
I have included an option for user to search for movies in the database by title.
I am using this piece of code to Display the rows Retured...

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<table border = "1px">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>RATING</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <td>Duration</td>
    <td>Actor</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = sanitize($search);
$search = '%'.$search.'%';
$conn = oci_connect("asim","asim","localhost/xe");
$stid = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT 
                film.film_id AS FID,
                film.title AS title,
                film.description AS description,
                category.name AS category,
                film.duration AS length,
                film.rating AS rating,
                CONCAT ( actor.first_name ,CONCAT(' ', actor.last_name)) AS actors
                FROM category 
                LEFT JOIN film_category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
                    LEFT JOIN film ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
                     JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
                     JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
                WHERE title LIKE '".$search."'");
    oci_execute($stid);
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
           print "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the results Displayed in a table form!
now what i want is that make the title or the film_id of every film fetched to be  a link.
and when clicked it should navigate to a specific page of that Movie.
That page could be like **index.php?id=1337**
and on the index page  $_GET['userid'] could be used to fetch info about that movie
The main problem is making the film_id or title or the whole row a link
I tried using the  tag but wasnt successful.
I am a newbie to PHP and oracle.
Any kind of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the anchor link generation example.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the documentation for `oci_fetch_array` found [here](http://php.net/oci_fetch_array) you will see that because you are using `OCI_ASSOC` parameter you are able to access the results using their named keys.

Inside you `while` loop you should be able to access the film_id using the column name you specified in the Oracle SELECT query, `FID`.

```
$row['FID']
```

You can then generate a link to that using the [html anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) `<a>`.

```
print '<a href="index.php?id=' . $row['FID'] . '">link text</a>';
```

Something similar to this is tying it all together, I have an example you can try below that will show you how to access the data as mentioned above, you should be able to continue from there.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print $row['PID'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: how can i wrap the array elemnt in anchor tag in this statement?
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print $row['PID'] . '<br />';
} and secondly how can i make a link like 
"href ="index.php$row['FILM_ID']""

Comment: When you make your anchor link, you can concatenate the php and html for your `print` statement as you have been, using the concatenate `.` operator. So `print '<a href="index.php?id=' . $row['FID'] . '">link text</a>';`